# PHP - .htaccess issue $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] is empty

Tags: php, .htaccess, model-view-controller, url-rewriting

On local host I was running my php (MVC) application with following rules in my .htaccess file:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond $1 !^(config|core|css|js|fonts|images|robots\.txt)

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

E.g. `localhost/myapp/register/login` will load the log in page.
But on a live server I'm having issues. The first problem I've faced was `No input file specified`. Reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557258/htaccess-issues-no-input-file-specified) I changed this line `RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php/$1 [L]` to `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]`. This solved the first problem but created another problem and now it's always loading the same/default view and controller no matter what the url is.

In my index.php has the following lines of code:

```
$url = isset($_SERVER['PATH_INFO']) ? explode('/', ltrim($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'], '/')) : [];
 // Route the request
 Router::route($url);
```

So, I checked the $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] value and it's empty. Now my question is why it's empty and how can i achieve the normal behavior of the urls.

Comment: _“Now my question is why it's empty”_ - _because_ you changed the URL, from one that _had_ a path info component, to one that _doesn’t_. Path info is the trailing part of the URL _path_ component, that comes after the file name that could by matched to a physically existing file. But you removed that portion from the URL path, and put it into the query string instead.

Answer (score 0):

So I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15042344/htaccess-rewriting-path-info-vars-to-empty-before-passing-to-template-not-remo). I have changed my `index.php` as following:

```
$url = isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ? explode('/', ltrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/')) : [];
 // Route the request
 Router::route($url);
```

... and now it's working as expected :) .

Answer (score 0):

It's so simple when we/I can use Laravel because it comes with **.htaccess** file automatically in a folder, apart of using Laravel you can use cPanel.

The **.htaccess** file should contain the following rules:

```bash
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```